# How to return subset of model as JSON from .Net Core SQL query?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm building an API with .NET Core and Entity Framework.

I have a Person model which maps to a table in my database. I want to return only a few of the fields from the table in JSON like so:

```
// GET: api/userInfo/abd45-4gtew-325fs-3525r
[HttpGet("{userGuid}")]
public IEnumerable<List> GetUserInfo([FromRoute] string userGuid)
{
    return _context.Person.FromSql($"SELECT p.PersonId, p.Name FROM 
    dbo.person p WHERE p.UserGuid= '{userGuid}'").ToList();
}
```

This returns an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Api.Models.Person>' to 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List>'.
```

which makes sense. But if I'm using the Person data context to retrieve the data, how can I return the subset?

Comment: That error says you tried to convert a List of persons into a List of Lists. The return type should be `IEnumerable<Person>`, `List<Person>` or `IList<Person>`

Comment: The issue I'm having is the Person model has many more fields that I don't want to return from this route.

Comment: that's a different question. The error in the question is caused because the return type is wrong. If you want to return different data, use a `Select()` that returns only the fields you want **before** you call `ToArray()` or `ToList(). Use `OK(thatData)` to return it. Change the return type to IActionResult. ASP.NET Core will take care of serializing the query results

Comment: It would be better to create a strongly typed class to represent those results though. This would allow you to easily add Swagger support and document what your API does

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to just return a JsonResult and create a dynamic object in your select. This would not require you to define the return type and assumes it is consumed by a front end client or a client that can handle JSON.

```
[HttpGet("{userGuid}")]
public JsonResult GetUserInfo([FromRoute] string userGuid)
{
    return Json(_context.Person
                   .Where(p => p.UserGuid == new Guid(userGuid))
                   .Select( p => new { PersonId = p.PersoniD, Name = p.Name } )
                   .ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a type to return, and change the controller to something like:

```
public class PersonSlim
{
  public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set}
}

[HttpGet("{userGuid}")]
public IEnumerable<PersonSlim> GetUserInfo([FromRoute] string userGuid)
{
    return _context.Person
                   .Where(p => p.UserGuid == new Guid(userGuid))
                   .Select( p => new PersonSlim() { PersonId = p.PersonID, Name = p.Name } )
                   .ToList();
}
```

Comment: How should I define the PersonSlim type?

Comment: It can just be an ordinary class.  No need to configure it as an EF entity.  See edit.

Comment: Ahah because when I define the class I get the error "cannot initalize type PersonSlim bwith a collection initializer because it does not implement IEnumerable"

Comment: That's an Object Initializer, not a Collection Initializer.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers